# php and mysql CRUD question

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I want to make a php application but i have too many tables with different names.Is there an existing CRUD library that can help me edit one table at a time by pointing directly to the table via a url like: `example.com/index/tablename` and editing the records.

Comment: I'm not sure, but that functionality would be fairly easy to build on top of an existing CRUD library.

Comment: I would recommend to look at http://adminer.org

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to directly edit the tables, it would be much easier (and safer) to use a dedicated tool such as [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, maybe you should use a DBMS, like [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)? Otherwise, I have no idea how are you going to edit data thru an url, and what would the GUI look like.

Comment: yes it is, wiki says "A Database Management System (DBMS) is a set of computer programs that controls the creation, maintenance, and the use of a database." he did not say it was a good one, but its one none the less

Comment: @Alessandro "A Database Management System (DBMS) is a set of computer programs that controls the creation, maintenance, and the use of the database with computer as a platform or of an organization and its end users." If PhpMyAdmin isn't a DBMS, then tell me what is it?

Comment: _"In short, a DBMS is a database program. Technically speaking, it is a software system that uses a standard method of cataloging, retrieving, and running queries on data. [...] Some DBMS examples include MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft Access, SQL Server, FileMaker, Oracle, RDBMS, dBASE, Clipper, and FoxPro."_ Source: [TechTerms](http://www.techterms.com/definition/dbms). phpMyAdmin is a tool to manage MySQL, which is a relational DBMS (RDBMS).

Comment: Hmm, anyways I'll stick with my opinion - Databases: mysql, oracle, mssql, etc; DBMS: phpmyadmin, microsoft sql server management studio express, etc.

Comment: Cite your sources. StackOverflow is a place for knowledge, not for wrong opinions. A _database_ is not a software: it's a collection of data. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems) for examples, or other questions here on StackOverflow: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848050/different-types-of-databases), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373566/what-is-the-best-dbms-for-the-job), [∞](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbms)

Answer (score 0):

you could give cakephp a go, the RAD development with bake could give you a simple crud app just typing a few commands in terminal. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake

Comment: If i use the code generator,there will be too many views that i will have to modify.

Comment: just throwing out some options for you.